# elasticsearch package import error

Tags: java, netbeans-7, elasticsearch

I am trying to import following packages in my .java file:-

```
import org.elasticsearch.action.index.IndexResponse;
import org.elasticsearch.client.Client;
import org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClient;
import org.elasticsearch.common.transport.InetSocketTransportAddress;
```

I am getting error that the above mentioned packages do not exist.

Comment: Well have you added the appropriate jar files to your classpath?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to download elastic search jar to make it work. Download it from [here](http://www.elasticsearch.org/download/).

And add it to your classpath.

Comment: i added elastic search using this command.
export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/java/classes:/opt/libraries/elasticsearch-0.19.10/lib/elasticsearch-0.19.10.jar

Comment: I am still getting the same error. I am using netbeans. Does it require some other settings??

Comment: check how to add jars to classpath in netbeans. I don't know how to do it in Netbeans. I use Eclipse.